# Issue with forloop in makefile

Tags: for-loop, makefile

I am new to makefile stuff.I wanted to run a for loop.But I got stuck in an error. The code and error is given below.

```
LIST = one two three
qwert:
    for number in $(LIST) ; do \
        echo $$number ; \
    done
```

ERROR:

```
number was unexpected this time
make:  ***[qwert] Error 255
```

What is the issue and how to solve this???

Comment: The error message looks like `cmd.exe`. Your code is fine, just use the correct shell.

Comment: @tripleee:I didnt understand..correct shell means

Comment: Bash, probably. A regular `make` should run `sh` even if it's not your preferred shell, so that part is clearly wrong here; but you reveal very little about your platform or Make version so this is necessarily all rather speculative.

Comment: installing cygwin solved that issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you try with a simple makefile defining the shell (as suggested by  tripleee) ?:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh

LIST = one two three

qwert:
  @for number in $(LIST) ; do \
  echo $$number ; \
  done
```

Comment: That should not be necessary if you have `/bin/sh` on your system.  I'm guessing it falls back to `cmd` as a very last recort on CygWin.